# How to name build artifact arbitrary name in Gradle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, aws-lambda, build.gradle

Following this guide to build AWS Lambdas into a ZIP file so that they can be deployed: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html

In my root `build.gradle`, I currently have this (which takes the lambdaZip task directly from the guide):

```
plugins {
    id 'my-company.plugin-plugin' version '1.0.0-rc.132'
}

dependencies {
    resolutionRules group:'my-company', name: 'gradle-resolution-rules', version: '12.0.0'
}

group = 'my-company'

subprojects {
    group = parent.group

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        ...deps...
    }

    idea.module.iml {
        beforeMerged { module ->
            module.dependencies.clear()
        }
    }

    ...more unrelated stuff...

    task lambdaZip(type: Zip) {
        from compileJava
        from compileGroovy
        from processResources
        into('lib') {
            from configurations.runtime
        }
    }
}
```

When I build my lambdas (e.g. `./gradlew :lambda:accountworker:lambdaZip`), it results in this file being created:

`/myproject/lambda/accountworker/build/distributions/accountworker-<PROJECT-VERSION_NUMBER_HERE>.zip`

Here's my problem - I want the built `.zip` file to be named `accountworker-LATEST.zip`, rather than the version number of the project.  I can't specify the `project.version` number as `LATEST` because that will completely mess up other parts of my build system.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Doh, just needed to specify the archive name...

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/AbstractArchiveTask.html#setArchiveName-java.lang.String-

```
task lambdaZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from compileGroovy
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtime
    }
    archiveName = "${baseName}-LATEST.zip"
}
```